# error call library cannot import name 'CommentTokenizer' from 'nltk.tokenize'

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-mining

my data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvbfE.png)

i need help, i want to cleaning my data with nltk tokenize, i already to install all library with `nltk.download('all')` i try this too

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
```

and re-installed too but still error say this :

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-135557339a7a> in <module>()
      9 
     10 #tokenize
---> 11 from nltk.tokenize import CommentTokenizer
     12 
     13 # Happy Emoticons

ImportError: cannot import name 'CommentTokenizer' from 'nltk.tokenize' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

this is the code

```
     #import stopword
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
stopwords_indonesia = stopwords.words('indonesian')
 
#import sastrawi
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory
factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()

#tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import CommentTokenizer
```

def clean_comment(comment):
# remove stock market tickers like $GE
comment = re.sub(r'$\w*', '', str(comment))

```
# remove hyperlinks
comment = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', str(comment))

# remove hashtags
# only removing the hash # sign from the word
comment = re.sub(r'#', '', str(comment))

#remove coma
comment = re.sub(r',','',str(comment))

#remove angka
comment = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', str(comment))

# tokenize comment
tokenizer = CommentTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True, reduce_len=True)
comment = tokenizer.tokenize(comment)

comment_clean = []    
for word in comment_tokens:
    if (word not in stopwords_indonesia and # remove stopwords
            word not in string.punctuation): # remove punctuation
        #comment_clean.append(word)
        stem_word = stemmer.stem(word) # stemming word
        comment_clean.append(stem_word)

return comment_clean
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The documentation for `nltk.tokenize` at https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html does not mention `CommentTokenizer`. Go back to your source and look more carefully at how it recommends you find (or write) this function.